# How to change the button image when tap started in sencha touch 2?

Tags: touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch.

I have a problem with the button tap event. Actually I have a button with a background image that is declared in the cls property of Button:

```
    Ext.define('app.view.common.PageHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    xtype: 'pageHeader',

    config: {

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                left: 10,
                top: 10,
                baseCls: 'null',
                cls: 'btn_back',            //with background:url('btn_img.png')
                listeners: {
                    tap: function () {
                        console.log('button tapped...');
                        //history.back();
                        this.removeCls('btn_back');
                        this.addCls('btn_press');
                    },
                    release: function () {
                        console.log('button released..');
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Now I just want to change the background image of the button when the button is tapped using removeCls() and addCls().

But from Sencha documentation I have not found any event like that.

So is there and way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove all listeners and handlers you have written. It's simply the `pressedCls` config for your button. For example:

`pressedCls: 'css_properties_when_the_button_is_pressed'`

Hope this helps.